# Number of solution to a Diophantine equation $ax+by\equiv c\pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Proof that the number of incongruent solution to $ax+by\equiv c\pmod n$ is $n\cdot \gcd(a,b,n)$. I have proven that there exists a solution to $ax+by\equiv c\pmod n$ if and only if $\gcd(a,b,n)\mid c$. But i could not go further

Comment: Huh?  If there is a solution $(x,y)$, then there are infinitely many solutions $(x-mb, y+ma)$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: mean incongruent solutions

Comment: What does mean incongruent solution, $x\not\equiv 0$ and $y \not\equiv0$ or $ax+by\not\equiv0$

Comment: Yes I mean the number of solutions that is distinct in $\mathbb{Z_n}$

Answer (score 1):

The equation $ax+by\equiv c$ mod $n$ may or may not have a solution $(u,v)$. You have found a condition for the existence of such a particular solution. Now count the incongruent solutions $(x',y')$ of the homogeneous equation $ax+by\equiv0$ mod $n$. If $(x',y')$ is such a solution then $(x,y):=(x'+u,y'+v)$  is a solution of $ax+by\equiv c$ mod $n$, and conversely.